# WPF DataGrid Column FIltering using Behaviors

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This is the simplest implementation of the 'DataGridBehavior' Class for column Filtering I could come up with:

```
    public static List<ColumnItem> GetColumnsFilter(DependencyObject obj) { ...}

    public static void SetColumnsFilter(DependencyObject obj, List<ColumnItem> value) { ...}

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnsFilterProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ColumnsFilter", typeof(List<ColumnItem>), typeof(DataGridBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnColumnsFilterChange));

private static void OnColumnsFilterChange(DependencyObject d, 
      DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var dg = d as DataGrid;
    if (dg == null) return;
    // Columns is a list and will never change
    if(e.NewValue == null && e.OldValue != null) dg.Loaded -= Handle_DataGridLoadedEvent;
    if (e.NewValue == null || ((List<ColumnItem>)e.NewValue).Count == 0) return;
    var Columns = ((List<ColumnItem>)e.NewValue);
    // Columns is a list and will never change.
    if (e.OldValue == null) 
    {
        dg.Loaded += Handle_DataGridLoadedEvent;
    }
    else // e.NeValue != null && e.OldValue != null (For some reason)
    {
        dg.Loaded -= Handle_DataGridLoadedEvent;
    }
}

    private static void Handle_DataGridLoadedEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dg = sender as DataGrid;
        var Columns = GetColumnsFilter(dg);
        foreach (var column in dg.Columns)
        {
            var col = Columns.FirstOrDefault(c => c.PropertyName == column.Header.ToString());
            if (col == null) continue;
            var binding = new Binding(nameof(col.IsShown));
            binding.Source = col;
            binding.Converter = new BooleanToVisibilityConverter();
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(column, DataGridColumn.VisibilityProperty, binding);
        }
    }
```

As for now, its use is straight forward.
In my ViewModel, I have a:

> List< ColumnItem> Columns {get; set;}

```
public class ColumnItem : IDeepClone<ColumnItem>
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }

    public Type PropertyType { get; set; }

    public bool IsShown { get; set; } = true;

    public List<ColumnItem> InnerProperties { get; set; }

    public TypeComplexity Complexity { get; set; } = TypeComplexity.SIMPLE; 
}
```

In my Xaml, I just add the behavior while binding it to the columns:

```
<DataGrid ItemSource={..} behaviors:DataGridBehavior.Columns={Binding Columns}/>
```

On Top of that, I usually have a listbox with a custom template that shows my columns in the format of: (Only for testing, better format to be used in the end product)

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"> 
<TextBlock Text={Binding PropertyName}/>
<CheckBox IsChecked={Binding IsShown}/>
</StackPanel>
```

Since I'm going to be using it extensively through out my program. I wanted to know if this implementation has any flaws. Should I use WeakEventManager or handle my e.OldValue && e.NewValue checks differently.
There are too many different answers on how to use it on the net, usually using xaml code behind (not that this implementation is further from that).
Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just a tip: for filtering I prefer `ICollectionView.Filter`. Something like [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-group-sort-and-filter-data-in-the-datagrid-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: I do use them in a sort in my data filtering, although the solution above is only to show or hide columns in a datagrid. No data filtering there.

Comment: Ah, ok. To show/hide a column you may just set Width=0 to the column, either through Converter. Just an option.

Comment: That's one way, but you still need a whole mechanism to do it. Probably a type to hold the Column Name and a show/hide boolean and a converter. Problem with that is that it means you can't use it while AutoGeneratedColumns=True, so you must set each column binding yourself and add the binding to visibility manually for every datagrid in your app. Also, setting the width to 0, makes it hard to show the column back again with unknown width.

Comment: _hard to show the column back again with unknown width._ Why? `DataTrigger` would do it for you. `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyProperty,RelativeSource=...}" Value="True"><Setter Property="Width" Value="0"/></DataTrigger>`, but I agree that it doesn't completely solve the issue but makes possible to simplify the solution...probably, i didn't try it with autogenerated columns.

Comment: Alright, I see what you meant now. I still believe it would be hard to implement for auto generated columns without behaviors. But thanks, I'll keep it in mind.
I just expanded the solution above, to use the list of columns to populate the columns on the datagrid in case of autogeneratedcolumns is false and no columns were custom created in xaml.